# How to addClass with css3 Animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I cant create nice finish for my css3 animation. Like go box-shadow to opacity 0. If i just add class with pause animation, it will be not nice, like blik stop.

**Javascript**

```
$(this).addClass('paused').delay(200).addClass('a-finish');
```

**CSS**

```
.paused {        
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;        
    -moz-animation-play-state:paused;        
    animation-play-state:paused;        
}

.a-finish { 
    -webkit-animation: 5s linear 0s normal none 1 wrap-done;            
}

@-webkit-keyframes wrap-done {         
    0% { box-shadow: 0 9px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) inset;}
    100% { box-shadow: 0 9px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) inset;}        
}
```

So i just need some like easy fade out animation by another css3 animation.

How i can do this with css3 and JQ?

Comment: If all you want is a fade out animation, have you tried `.fadeOut()`?

Comment: Ofc i not need just fadeOut =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. What i created:

**Javascript**

```
$('.class').addClass('blink');                       <-Start some animation.
$('.class').on('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {   <-When animation end.
    $(.class).addClass('paused');                    <-Stop animation.
    $(.class).addClass('a-finish');                  <-Start finish animation.
}
```

**Css**

```
.blink {
    ...some blik animation
}

.paused {        
-webkit-animation-play-state:paused;        
-moz-animation-play-state:paused;        
animation-play-state:paused;        
}

.a-finish { 
    -webkit-animation: 5s linear 0s normal none 1 wrap-done;            
}

@-webkit-keyframes wrap-done {         
    0% { box-shadow: 0 9px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) inset;}
    100% { box-shadow: 0 9px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) inset;}        
}
```

**And this is not work!!**

So if animation is paused by `animation-play-state:paused;` we cant add new. So i just use removeClass with previous animation and start new for finish.

Comment: `webkitTransitionEnd` is triggered by transitions, not animations. Try `webkitAnimationEnd`.